# Spotlight: Show recently opened files of application

Tags: macos, spotlight, search, ventura

With *macOS Monterey* (and before) it was possible in **Spotlight to show the recent files of an application** before opening the application.
E.g.:

1. Open Spotlight (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>)
2. Search 'Pages'
3. Arrow down to highlight the *Pages* application
4. Press 'tab' key on your keyboard
5. You see a list of the recent files opened with Pages

That was possible with a lot of applications:
Pages, Keynote, VSCode, SourceTree, Final Cut, ...

⚠️ **With *macOS Ventura* this isn't possible anymore.
Any tips how to enable that again?**

[image]

Comment: While I had never used (nor heard of) that feature it does work for me on my M1 MacBook Pro with macOS 13.1. So it is possible that it is a cache that was deleted or that function will return after some use of Pages rather than an intentional change in Ventura.

Comment: In Ventura recently opened files are displayed under "Documents" block below search box. It will not open separate right pane to display them.

Comment: @SteveChambers I tried to reset the Spotlight index and opened different files with different apps. Still doesn't work for me (M1 MacBook Pro macOS 13.1)

Comment: @AivarPaalberg unfortunately this doesn't work for all applications and for me it only shows one recent file of some applications

Comment: Yeah it looks like this (great) feature was killed in Ventura. Monopoly is a productivity destroyer.